# How to add all the values of an array and divide by the total number of entries?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$prices = array();`. This array contains a number of entries that show a price.

For example `€ 2.500`

My goal is to add all this values and have the average number. But first, to have the `€ 2.500` in the format of `2500`

This is what I know and it is done by using

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $variable);
```

What is a way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: This is also known as "calculate average".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_map` to apply that regex to each element.

```
$avg = array_sum(array_map(function($v){
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $v);
}, $prices)) / count($prices);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I can't get it working. I edited my question adding this `$prices = array();` instead of `prices[]`

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(34) "€ 1.500" [1]=> string(34) "€ 4.500"` and continues

Comment: @Shilloftanos: So, you have a 2D array?  What is `$prices[0]` versus `$prices[1]`?  Do you want the average of the *entire* `$prices` array?  Do you want the average of each array in `$prices`?

Comment: @Shilloftanos: How are you creating it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($prices as $index => $value)
   $total += preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $value);

echo "€" . number_format($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCleanArray($prices)
{
    $pricesCleaned = array();

    foreach ($prices as $value)
    {
        $pricesCleaned.push(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', '', $value));
    }

    return $pricesCleaned;
}
```

After this method call you will get array with numbers which you can manipulate further.